# Python pandas / matplotlib annotating labels above bar chart columns

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

How do I add the label for the value to display above the bars in the bargraph here:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df=pd.DataFrame({'Users': [ 'Bob', 'Jim', 'Ted', 'Jesus', 'James'],
                 'Score': [10,2,5,6,7],})

df = df.set_index('Users')
df.plot(kind='bar',  title='Scores')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

A solution without accessing the DataFrame is to use the patches attribute:

```
ax = df.plot.bar(title="Scores")
for p in ax.patches:
    ax.annotate(str(p.get_height()), xy=(p.get_x(), p.get_height()))
```

Note you have to play around with the xy kwarg (2nd arg) to get the label position you desire.

#### Vertical Bars

I found this formatting to be the best in general:

```
ax.annotate("%.2f" % p.get_height(), (p.get_x() + p.get_width() / 2., p.get_height()), ha='center', va='center', xytext=(0, 10), textcoords='offset points')
```

#### Horizontal Bars

I found the following format to work well with horizontal bars:

```
ax.annotate("%.2f" % p.get_width(), (p.get_x() + p.get_width(), p.get_y()), xytext=(5, 10), textcoords='offset points')
```

Answer (score 17):

Capture the axis where the plot is drawn into, then manipulate it as a usual `matplotlib` object. Putting the value above the bar will be something like this:

```py
ax = df.plot(kind='bar',  title='Scores', rot=0)
ax.set_ylim(0, 12)
for i, label in enumerate(list(df.index)):
    score = df.loc[label]['Score']
    ax.annotate(str(score), (i, score + 0.2))
```

[image]