# How to change Pandas plot annotation to whole number?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I've been using the line of code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23591254/python-pandas-matplotlib-annotating-labels-above-bar-chart-columns/34598688#34598688) post in order to annotate total values on top of my columns in a bar plot, but I can't seem to figure out how to get the result in a whole number with no decimal places?

```
ax = df.plot.bar(title="Scores")
for p in ax.patches:
    ax.annotate("%.2f" % p.get_height(), (p.get_x() + p.get_width() / 2., p.get_height()), ha='center', va='center', xytext=(0, 10), textcoords='offset points')
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just convert the number to an `int`:

```
ax = df.plot.bar(title="Scores")
for p in ax.patches:
    ax.annotate(str(int(p.get_height())), (p.get_x() + p.get_width() / 2., p.get_height()), ha='center', va='center', xytext=(0, 10), textcoords='offset points')
```

---

Demo:

[image]